# Estimating the error function using Monte Carlo integration

Tags: integration, python, monte-carlo, error-function

How do I perform Monte Carlo integration on the error function

$erf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt(\pi)}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$

I have to estimate this using python but I'm not sure how the integral works at all. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you supposed to estimate $\operatorname{erf}x$ with MC integration?

Comment: I'm afraid "Monte Carlo integration on the error function" is a meaningless combination of words. Monte Carlo *can* approximate definite integrals, using (pseudo-)random numbers, but you'd have to tell us what integral exactly.

Comment: I have to evaluate the error function using Monte Carlo integration, I've never done Monte Carlo integration before so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monte Carlo integration is a technique used to estimate integrals. The key is to write the integrand as the product of a probability density function and some other function so that the integral effectively becomes an expected value problem.  In your case:

$$
\operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2 x}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}/x\,\mathrm dt=\frac{2 x}{\sqrt\pi}\mathsf E(\exp(-X^2)),
$$

where $X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,x)$. Hence, we may *estimate* the error function by sampling $n$ psudeo-random variates from the $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,x)$ density and then computing
$$
\widehat{\operatorname{erf}(x)}=\frac{2x}{n\sqrt\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n\exp(-x_i^2)
$$

In MATLAB we may implement this as

```
data=rand(1e6,1);
erfEst=@(x) 2*x/sqrt(pi)*mean(exp(-(x*data).^2));
```

Comment: Can i ask, why did you include x in the fraction and divide by x in the integral

Comment: So, did you multiplied the function by x/x to make it a product of a probability density function and another function? Also, what does the large E in the notation represent?

Comment: @Redone123 Yes. The point of multiplying by $x/x$ was I could write the integrand as the product of a function and (in this example) the uniform pdf on $(0,x)$. The $\mathsf E(\exp(-X^2))$ denotes the expected value of $\exp(-X^2)$